# How to pass the type to indexBy in Doctrine relationships?

Tags: symfony, collections, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine in my Symfony project and I have entities with relationships. In my User entity, I have a one-to-many relationship with the `Address` entity, and I'm using the `indexBy` option to index the addresses by their IDs.

Here's an example of my entities:

```php
class User
{
    #[Id]
    #[Column(type: 'uuid')]
    #[GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[CustomIdGenerator(class: UuidGenerator::class)]
    protected \Symfony\Component\Uid\Uuid $id;

    #[OneToMany(mappedBy: 'user', targetEntity: Address::class, indexBy: 'id')]
    protected Collection $addresses;
}

class Address
{
    #[Id]
    #[Column(type: 'uuid')]
    #[GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[CustomIdGenerator(class: UuidGenerator::class)]
    protected \Symfony\Component\Uid\Uuid $id;

    #[ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'addresses')]
    #[JoinColumn(name: 'user_id', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    protected User $user;
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I retrieve the list of addresses, the index is created as a binary 16 value instead of using the `UUIDType` provided by `symfony/uid`.

Here's the code I'm using to retrieve the addresses:

```
$user = $em->getRepository(User::class)->find($userId);
$addresses = $user->getAddresses();
$addressId = '...';

if (!$addresses->containsKey($addressId)) {
    // throw exception
}
```

Is there a way to create a handler or manipulate the UUID instance so that the value is used as a string instead of binary in the index?

I appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Why yours primary key there are uuid!?

Comment: Is there a particular reason I should avoid it? @Francisco

Comment: Performance in join queries, is the main reason.